# Looking for the title of an electro/indie song: "We can't be friends"

Tags: identify-this-song, electronic-music

I'm going crazy searching for an electro / indie song. I remember in the official video song there is a man (drawn) that is running and the title I think (or lyrics) contain "we can't be friends", or "i love you till the end.." or it's about the impossibility to be friends because the man (that is running on the video) is in love with the girl !

Please any help ???

Answer (score 2):

I've found it : Its DatA - Rapture [Here is it (great song)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_iwT9XNPc8)